# Eclipse IDE for JavaScript and web developers does not show inline error in code

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, nodeclipse, wildwebdeveloper

I have recently downloaded Eclipse for Javascript and Web Developers and imported one of my node JS project in it. Eveything is fine except I am not getting inline errors like I get on Eclipse for Java/C++ development.

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ :

[image]

Eclipse IDE for Javascript and Web Developers:

[image]

Below are the version details:

```
Eclipse IDE for JavaScript and Web Developers
Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0)
Build id: 20200313-1211
OS: Linux, v.5.5.13-200.fc31.x86_64, x86_64 / gtk 3.24.13, WebKit 2.28.0
Java version: 1.8.0_242
```

Why is eclipse IDE is not detecting the errors and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Because the function might exist at runtime.

Comment: Isn't someNonExistenceFunction() a global funtion which should be available in the project ? Also I imported same project on vscode and it shows error on line 101 with underline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get really good inline validation by installing CodeMix into your Eclipse IDE. CodeMix is based on Code (I saw you also use vs code), so you might get familiar right away.

Cheers!